# Python regex for fmtp

Tags: python, regex

My script receives the line below, and I need to filter only fmtp attributes, I need to strip `a=fmtp:XXXX` (max 3 digits) from the line below.

```
a=fmtp:96 mode-change-period=1; mode-change-capability=2; mode-change-neighbor=0; max-red=0; octet-align=0
```

My below Regex currently strips `a=fmtp:` but not the 2 (max 3) digits after that

```
fmtp_attributes=re.findall("(?<=fmtp:).*$",a_line)
```

Please help me how to strip the next two/three digits after `a=fmtp:`

Appreciate your help

Comment: Use `re.findall(r'fmtp:\d{2,3}\s*(.*)', s)`

Comment: That works without any flaw.Thank you very much for the prompt response Wiktor, Also, Can you please help me how to replace the ; to , and make each item as individual list item 
mode-change-period=1; mode-change-capability=2; mode-change-neighbor=0; max-red=0; octet-align=0

Comment: use `split(",")` after you got the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the part of string you want, you may use

```
r'fmtp:\d{2,3}\s*(.*)'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/n7ABpG/1)

**Details**

- `fmtp:` - a literal substring
- `\d{2,3}` - 2 or 3 digits
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*)` - Capturing group 1 (this is what you need to grab): any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible

See [Python demo](https://ideone.com/GT2w28):

```
import re
s="a=fmtp:96 mode-change-period=1; mode-change-capability=2; mode-change-neighbor=0; max-red=0; octet-align=0"
m = re.search(r'fmtp:\d{2,3}\s*(.*)', s)
if m:
    print("The text extracted: {}".format(m.group(1)))
    dt = dict([x.split("=") for x in m.group(1).split("; ")])
    print("The list of attribute values: {}".format(dt))
```

Output:

```
The text extracted: mode-change-period=1; mode-change-capability=2; mode-change-neighbor=0; max-red=0; octet-align=0
The list of attribute values: {'octet-align': '0', 'max-red': '0', 'mode-change-capability': '2', 'mode-change-period': '1', 'mode-change-neighbor': '0'}
```

Comment: I have input string as below 

     a=rtpmap:121 AMR-WB/16000/1 \na=fmtp:121 octet-align=1;mode-set=1\na=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000 \na=fmtp:101 0-15

I have to create 4 dictionaries, with two rtpmap lines and 2 fmtp lines, 
My function takes these dictionaries as inputs and compares with the server response 
Each line in my input string is separated with \n , Kindly help me to formulate function for the same